# automatically request desktop site on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, request, desktop, responsive

So my site is currently hosted at www.indianaporter.com, it works perfectly on computers but on mobile the video background and parallax background aren't working. I know that the plugins have been stated to not work on mobile but on my android phone they completely work when I tick the request desktop site (using chrome). So obviously it wouldn't be good web design to leave a note asking visitors to do that manually, is there a way using java or something to do this automatically?

Btw im using

https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/

https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer

Help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you solve your issue?